# Normalize probability distribution by variance of each class

Tags: distributions, language-models

I have several topics that I will collect language data for. Using [Mturk](https://www.mturk.com/) I will ask responders to write sentences for each topic. The sentences will be used to train a language model. Language models work best when their training data is representative of the data they will be used to evaluate.

I have found that the topics are not equally common in real life so I will give Mturk questions to responders in a distribution that aligns with the probability distribution of topics.

I have determined that the number of ngrams (unique word pairs) in the topics vary greatly and would like to update the probability distribution of my topics to account for each topic's ngram count.

My approach is to take the product of each topic's ngram count and its distribution:

```
| Topic   | Distribution (%) | Ngram Count | Product |
|---------|------------------|-------------|---------|
| Weather | 50               | 100         | 5000    |
| Sports  | 25               | 70          | 1750    |
| Music   | 25               | 20          | 500     |
```

I then find the probability distribution of the Product column and use that as my "normalized" distribution. Where the normalized distribution for Weather is `5000/sum(Product)`.

```
| Topic   | Distribution (%) | Ngram Count | Product | Normalized |
|---------|------------------|-------------|---------|------------|
| Weather | 50               | 100         | 5000    | .69        |
| Sports  | 25               | 70          | 1750    | .24        |
| Music   | 25               | 20          | 500     | .07        |
```

Is this correct?

Comment: I did not fully understand your question! However, there is a post [here] that might help you. [here]: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/336514/how-to-combine-two-sets-of-samples-from-an-unnormalised-distribution/351220#351220

Comment: Thanks KiaSh, I updated the wording and added an example of what I have tried so far.

Comment: I am also not understanding what you are trying to accomplish here.  What is `Distribution (%)`?

Comment: @ERT The percentage of weight that topic has in the probability distribution of all topics. So 50% of the real life data is about Weather.